# How do i scan my AWS S3 buckets for malicious content/objects?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware, amazon-s3

I am setting up AWS SFTP which uses s3 to store files. I am setting up sftp to exchange files with third party organisations. When i receive files i want to ensure no malicious content is received. How do i scan objects that arrive into my s3?

I have had a look at google and stackoverflow but not finding any definitive way to do achieve this.

I would appreciate any help/guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no support to prevent malware uploads in the present [S3 API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html) or [S3 Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html).

What is possible is to analyze the incoming objects outside of S3, e.g. download and inspection on a machine which is equipped with software that can identify malware.

You might use only [PUT permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html) to prevent further processing until your inspection has cleared the incoming objects.

Amazon Macie seems to be able to classify your S3 objects and raise [alerts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/macie/latest/userguide/macie-alerts.html) (File hosting, Ransomware alerts), I have not tried it though.

SFTP access then is also controllable via permissions.

It would require some self written application to run all this.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your response. this is just what i was thinking. I think its abit short sighted that AWS does not provide such a capability / add on service to s3.

Answer (score 2):

you can try the approach of using ClamAV which is an open-source AV.

https://github.com/upsidetravel/bucket-antivirus-function

Also Second approach if you can use the Virustotal enterprise API for scanning S3 buckets that's another thing I am trying out currently.

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of folks who have taken ClamAV, as suggested above, and productized it. Along with ideas of providing use of other scanning engines. Checkout AWS Marketplace: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results?x=0&y=0&searchTerms=s3+antivirus.

You can certainly build it yourself, but these are supported and robust.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this would be to create a specific-purpose AWS Lambda function which would execute a well-known vulnerability scanner or firewall (e.g. the open-source ClamavNet). This would be triggered upon the object's arrival on S3.